# Jenkins log parser doesn't show the Log Parser Trend when used in Pipeline

Tags: parsing, jenkins, logging, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I use the Jenkins log parser in pipeline as follow:

```
    pipeline{
        agent {
            node {
                label 'myNode'
            }
        }
    stages {
    //some parallel stages
    }
    post {
      always { 
      logParser failBuildOnError: true, projectRulePath: 'PathToParsingFile', showGraphs: true, unstableOnWarning: true, useProjectRule: true,  parsingRulesPath:''
    
            }
       }
    }
```

I do have the parsing result when I launch a build.

The problem is that I don't have the "Log Parser Trend" that I can see when I use a freestyle Job.

[Log Parser Trend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a1wr.png)